# Flutter camera frame drops when switching between pages

Tags: dart, flutter

I have tried to use the [Flutter camera plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) (0.2.1) in combination with a PageView and a BottomNavigationBar, but everytime the page gets switched, a few frames get skipped and the UI freezes for a second.

I've simplified my codebase for this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Pages());

class Pages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PagesState createState() => _PagesState();
}

class _PagesState extends State<Pages> {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _page = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = new PageController();
    super.initState();
  }

  void navTapped(int page) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(page,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      this._page = page;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("CameraTest"),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[Feed(), Camera(), Profile()],
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Feed")),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.camera), title: new Text("Capture")),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.person), title: new Text("Profile"))
          ],
          onTap: navTapped,
          currentIndex: _page,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  List<CameraDescription> _cameras;
  CameraController _controller;

  initCameras() async{
    _cameras = await availableCameras();
    _controller = new CameraController(_cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    await _controller.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initCameras();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_controller == null || !_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return new Center(
        child: new Text("Waiting for camera...", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
      );
    }
    return new AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: new CameraPreview(_controller));
  }
}

//just placeholder widgets

class Feed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: new Text("Feed"));
  }
}

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: new Text("Profile"));
  }
}
```

There are basically three pages with the middle one showing a camera-preview
([how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXN1q.png)), but on switching to the camera and back from it [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZQHf.gif) happens. This is really annoying since it ruins the user experience and is not smooth at all. The lag appears when calling initCameras() or when disposing the camera-controller. I tried using initCameras() in combination with a FutureBuilder, which didn't help at all, and running the method in a seperate isolate, but platform calls seem to be only allowed on the main isolate. It seems a bit weird to me since opening the camera doesn't need too much cpu power, so an async method should be fine. I am aware there is an [image-picker plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker), but I want to have the preview in the app directly. I have also considered to run initCameras() on app start, but i don't want to have the camera running all the time when the user is just using another page of the app.

Is there any way to improve upon initCameras() or perhaps use a different implementation to fix the stuttering? I wouldn't even care if it takes a second to load, but i don't want any frame skips.

I followed the [example](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) on the bottom of the camera page.

Tested on physical devices as well as emulators on different Android versions.

Comment: Is this only with debug builds or also with release builds?

Comment: Happens in release as well as debug builds

Comment: Then it's probably a good idea to create a bug report with the information that allows to reproduce.

Comment: alright, thank you

Comment: @LeonP Did you create a bug report?

Comment: No, my project back then wasn't very serious, but i have not used the camera plugin since then so i also don't know how much has changed/if there have been any improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar issue by adding a delay before initializing the camera:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  initCameras();
});
```

This way the `initCameras()` is called after the page navigation animation is completed. You can show a `CircularProgressIndicator()` to make this delay more user friendly.
I am sure there is a more neat way to work around the issue, but this seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Probably a valid workaround, but certainly not ideal. Adding timed delays so other stuff can load properly never seems like a good idea. But that's basically what you already said anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use image path in the different page than store image path as the global variable, and use it where you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not figure out to which image path you are to referring. Just to clarify, I am trying to display a live camera preview, not an already captured image. Could you provide some more information on what you mean?